# ActiveRecord relation one to one with belongs to rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Consider the following case. I want to restrict users to have at most one address, so my goal is to have at most one foreign key user_id in the address table set.

User has one address, which reflects the respective models :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, dependent: :destroy
end
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validate :user_association

  def user_association
    unless Address.where(user_id: user.id).count == 0
      errors.add(:user_id, 'Only one address per user')
    end
  end
end
```

I'm creating address from the User model, here is that bit (**first way**):

```
def create_address_relation
    a = Address.create(address_type: @type.to_s, user_id: id)
    self.address = a
end
```

**Second way** :

```
def create_address_relation
    create_address(address_type: @type.to_s)
end
```

**First way of creating address relation (User has no address relation):**

1. Invoke create_address_relation on `user` instance. The address relation gets created, great!
2. Invoke create_address_relation on `user` instance which already has address relation. Another address gets created, not so great! I wonder what am I doing wrong with validations

**Second way of creating address relation (User has no address relation):**

1. Invoke create_address_relation on `user` instance. The address relation gets created, great!
2. Invoke create_address_relation on `user` instance which already has address relation. Here is the weird bit, the current address `deleted_at` field gets set to true. And now the user doesn't have address relation.

What am I doing wrong here? And what is the right way to ensure that there is at most one user per address?

**Update:**
I can add a unique index on user_id in the addresses table or I can check manually in the code if the address exists don't create another address record.

It's not as nice and clean as validations, so I'd prefer that solution, but for now I got temp solution in place.

Comment: In 1-1 association, we don't need to worry about the records, as Rails will automatically delete the previous record if we try to create a second record. Are you using `paranoia` in Address model?

Comment: Yes the rails will do that, but in case the address has relation to other parts of the system, that can cause some analytics confusion. @Kuldeep yes I'm using paranoia. thanks

Comment: In your first way, try: `self.address.find_or_create_by_address_type(@type.to_s)` and then update your `user_association ` method to: `if user.reload.address.present?`.

Comment: I'm sure that would work but still doesn't explain why the validations are not working. I can also add a unique index on my db to be really sure